# I'm getting a warning that disk space on C: is below 5% when it's not

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, disk-space-utilization, sql-server-2012

It's a database server running SQL Server 2012 on Windows Server 2012 R2.

**C: is the boot/windows drive, but does NOT contain the data (mdf), log (ldf), or temp files (tempdb.mdf) for the database.** So it's not any of those growing and shrinking automatically.

It last happened 19:30 last night, but has happened before. There's 15GB free (25%) of 60GB and has been since Friday, nobody's been one since.

It's an ISAM (monitoring software) alert that sends out an email to me. I guess the alert could be wrong.

But is there any reason the free space on the boot/windows drive might just fall by 12GB, by itself? Say, a temp file for virtual memory or something being created? On a WS 2012 server?

Comment: A VSS snapshot during a backup? Are you checking the disk space at the time of the alert?

Answer (score 1):

@joeqwerty I think is possibly on to your problem.  I have experienced issues with virtual machine manager (VMM) shutting down servers due to disk space issues, and it was VSS related.  There is a brief period when a VSS snapshot occurs when the OS can report the wrong storage amount, if your software picks it up at that time it could be your issue.  In my case - I had some I/O contention issues and it seemed to make the window larger than it normally would be during a backup, and it caused the monitoring software to take action.

Comment: This is the best possibility I've seen. Any idea how I can avoid the false warning? What if I told it to not notify me unless disk space was low twice in a row, say 5 seconds apart? Or minutes?